# Select parents with children in multiple places

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `boxes` and `things` that partially model a warehouse.

A box may

- contain a single thing
- contain one or more boxes
- be empty

There is only one level of nesting: a box may be a parent or a child, but not a grandparent.

I want to identify parent boxes that satisfy these criteria:

- have children in more than one place
- only child boxes associated with a quantity > 0 are to be considered

Using the example data the box with id 2 should be selected, because it has children with quantities in two places.  Box 1 should be rejected because all it's children are in a single place and box 3 should be rejected because while it has children in two places, only one place has a positive quantity.

The query should work on all supported versions of Postgresql.  Both tables contain around two million records.

**Setup:**

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS things;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS boxes;

CREATE TABLE boxes (
    id serial primary key,
    box_id integer references boxes(id)
);


CREATE TABLE things (
    id serial primary key,
    box_id integer references boxes(id),
    place_id integer,
    quantity integer
);


INSERT INTO boxes (box_id)
  VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3), (3);


INSERT INTO things (box_id, place_id, quantity)
  VALUES (4, 1, 1), (5, 1, 1), (6, 2, 1), (7, 3, 1), (8, 4, 1), (9, 5, 0);
```

I have come up this solution

```sql
WITH parent_places AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.box_id, t.place_id) b.box_id, t.place_id
    FROM boxes b 
    JOIN things t ON b.id = t.box_id
    WHERE t.quantity > 0
)

SELECT box_id, COUNT(box_id)
FROM parent_places
GROUP BY box_id
HAVING COUNT(box_id) > 1;
```

but I'm wondering if I've missed a more obvious solution (or if my solution has any errors that I've overlooked).

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0f65d6563df000d50905146d3aaa32eb)

Comment: A box can have either a single box or (xor) a single thing inside? Do I understand you correctly ?

Comment: If so, the may not be a box with 2 things in it.  In your test case I see there are 2 boxes in boxes 1, 2, 3..  According to the example it seems a box may have several boxes in it, but a single thing. Please clarify the constraints on the data.

Comment: Ah sorry I was too focussed on "things".  A box may contain zero or more boxes.  I'll edit the question to clarify.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way a box to have things with different location properties is only when the box has several boxes with things in them.

```
SELECT
  b2.box_id, COUNT(DISTINCT place_id)
FROM
  boxes b2
  JOIN things t ON b2.id = t.box_id AND quantity > 0
WHERE
  b2.box_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  b2.box_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT place_id) > 1;
```

I see no reason for using CTE like in your example. I think you should use the simplest query that does the job.

Comment: "I think you should use the simplest query that does the job" -> precisely my motivation for asking the question!  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: i'm glad to help :)